# Printing all combinations of balanced parenthesis - missing cases when the argument is larger than 4

Tags: python

I have been trying to tackle the problem in the title for some time now, and I have come up with the following code:

```
def parenthesize(lst, num):
    if num == 1:
        lst.append('()')
        return lst
    a1 = []
    a2 = []
    a = parenthesize(a1, num - 1)
    b = parenthesize(a2, num - 1)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = '(' + a[i] + ')'
    for i in range(len(b)):
        tmp = b[i]
        b[i] = tmp + '()'
        tmp = '()' + tmp
        if tmp not in b:
            b.append(tmp)
    for i in a:
        lst.append(i)
    for i in b:
        lst.append(i)
    return lst

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = []
    n=5
    res = parenthesize(lst, n)
    print(res)
    print(len(res))
```

Now, when n is equal to or larger than 5, I am missing some cases (e.g.: when n is 5, it prints 40 pairs instead of 42, and difference grows exponentially as n grows). I have been unable to realize why this is happening or which cases am I missing.
(I have a working solution from GfG, but I want to understand what I did wrong here).